# Display line on current time week view jqueryFullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

How to enable a line that follows the current time in the agenda view of the calendar, like in google calendar has the red line?

Comment: This question has now been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813454/fullcalendar-current-time-line-on-week-view-and-day-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not yet implemented, but in the queue:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=143

Comment: Anything I can do to help speed up the process?