# fullcalendar current time line on week view and day view

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I understand that according to this issue ticket on google code http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=143 that there is a soloution floating around, however I cant seem to find it.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to show a [red solid line on the current time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Bains_line) on the calendar

Comment: @Silvestre has the correct answer. Its now available in v2.6.0. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/nowIndicator/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function setTimeline(view) {
    var parentDiv = jQuery(".fc-agenda-slots:visible").parent();
    var timeline = parentDiv.children(".timeline");
    if (timeline.length == 0) { //if timeline isn't there, add it
        timeline = jQuery("<hr>").addClass("timeline");
        parentDiv.prepend(timeline);
    }

    var curTime = new Date();

    var curCalView = jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView');
    if (curCalView.visStart < curTime && curCalView.visEnd > curTime) {
        timeline.show();
    } else {
        timeline.hide();
        return;
    }

    var curSeconds = (curTime.getHours() * 60 * 60) + (curTime.getMinutes() * 60) + curTime.getSeconds();
    var percentOfDay = curSeconds / 86400; //24 * 60 * 60 = 86400, # of seconds in a day
    var topLoc = Math.floor(parentDiv.height() * percentOfDay);

    timeline.css("top", topLoc + "px");

    if (curCalView.name == "agendaWeek") { //week view, don't want the timeline to go the whole way across
        var dayCol = jQuery(".fc-today:visible");
        var left = dayCol.position().left + 1;
        var width = dayCol.width()-2;
        timeline.css({
            left: left + "px",
            width: width + "px"
        });
    }

}
```

And then in the setup:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
        try {
            setTimeline();
        } catch(err) {}
    },
```

and in the css:

```
.timeline {
    position: absolute;
    left: 59px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Only tried this on week-view since that's all I use.

Good luck.

Edit:

To get the timeline to update during the day you could try something like this in the viewDisplay:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
            if(first){
                first = false;
            }else {
                window.clearInterval(timelineInterval);
            }
            timelineInterval = window.setInterval(setTimeline, 300000);
            try {
                setTimeline();
            } catch(err) {}
        },
```

You will need to set first=true in the top of the  tag. This will move the timeline every 300 second = 5 minutes. You can lower it if you need it more smooth..

Comment: Thank you, that worked a charm, will this get updated as the day goes on if the user stays on the same page or will it just stay at the current time it was loaded.

Comment: The only thing that did not work is the time zone, it things it is 3:22pm when right now is 4:22

Comment: Not sure about the time zone thing, if new Date() gives you the correct time you should be allright I guess?!

Comment: working great. but there is a problem with timezone :( not sure how to fix that

Comment: This has been solved in version 2.6.0 [nowIndicator](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/nowIndicator/)

Answer (score 14):

It has been solved in the new version of FullCalendar (2.6.0)

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/nowIndicator/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({       
    nowIndicator: true
});
```

[image: nowIndicator]

Comment: This is the correct answer for the most current version of fullcalendar.

Comment: hi @Silvestre, how can i set sun, mon tue on left and 10am, 11am, 12pm on top? I mean the reversed view of this.

Answer (score 12):

Magnus Winter's solution works very well, but it doesn't consider fullcalender options minTime and maxTime. If they are set then the timeline is misplaced.

To fix this replace the definition of curSeconds and percentOfDay in Magnus Winter's code with:

```
var curSeconds = ((curTime.getHours() - curCalView.opt("minTime")) * 60 * 60) + (curTime.getMinutes() * 60) + curTime.getSeconds();
var percentOfDay = curSeconds / ((curCalView.opt("maxTime") - curCalView.opt("minTime")) * 3600); // 60 * 60 = 3600, # of seconds in a hour
```

Answer (score 7):

Great solution, accumulated all the changes in the thread to get this working for **fullcalendar-2.1.0-beta1** and made some minor changes so it would work for me.

> ```
> var timelineInterval;
>
> $calendar.fullCalendar({
>   ...,
>   viewRender: function(view) {              
>     if(typeof(timelineInterval) != 'undefined'){
>       window.clearInterval(timelineInterval); 
>     }
>     timelineInterval = window.setInterval(setTimeline, 300000);
>     try {
>       setTimeline();
>     } catch(err) {}
>   },
>   ...
> });
>
> function setTimeline(view) {
>   var parentDiv = $('.fc-slats:visible').parent();
>   var timeline = parentDiv.children(".timeline");
>   if (timeline.length == 0) { //if timeline isn't there, add it
>     timeline = $("<hr>").addClass("timeline");
>     parentDiv.prepend(timeline);
>   }
>
>   var curTime = new Date();
>
>   var curCalView = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getView');
>   if (curCalView.intervalStart < curTime && curCalView.intervalEnd > curTime) {
>     timeline.show();
>   } else {
>     timeline.hide();
>     return;
>   }
>   var calMinTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("minTime"));
>   var calMaxTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("maxTime"));
>   var curSeconds = (( ((curTime.getHours() * 60) + curTime.getMinutes()) - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60) + curTime.getSeconds();
>   var percentOfDay = curSeconds / ((calMaxTimeInMinutes - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60);
>
>   var topLoc = Math.floor(parentDiv.height() * percentOfDay);
>   var timeCol = $('.fc-time:visible');
>   timeline.css({top: topLoc + "px", left: (timeCol.outerWidth(true))+"px"});
>
>   if (curCalView.name == "agendaWeek") { //week view, don't want the timeline to go the whole way across
>     var dayCol = $(".fc-today:visible");
>     var left = dayCol.position().left + 1;
>     var width = dayCol.width() + 1;
>     timeline.css({left: left + "px", width: width + "px"});
>   }
> }
>
> function strTimeToMinutes(str_time) {
>   var arr_time = str_time.split(":");
>   var hour = parseInt(arr_time[0]);
>   var minutes = parseInt(arr_time[1]);
>   return((hour * 60) + minutes);
> }
> ```

### **My changes**

Had to change

```
var parentDiv = jQuery(".fc-agenda-slots:visible").parent();
```

to

```
var parentDiv = jQuery(".fc-slats:visible").parent();
```

Otherwise no timeline would be rendered at all. Guess Full Calendar changed this.

---

Then I had an issue with the left pos of the line in day view so I changed

```
timeline.css("top", topLoc + "px");
```

to

```
var timeCol = $('.fc-time:visible');
timeline.css({top: topLoc + "px", left: (timeCol.outerWidth(true))+"px"});
```

---

Also the timeline width in agendaWeek came out wrong so i changed

```
var width = dayCol.width() - 2;
```

to

```
var width = dayCol.width() + 1;
```

Didn't go into why this was, just changed it so it would look right.

Answer (score 6):

Martin Pabst made a good point, but it doesn't work if you set min and max time as strings (ex. "07:30").

To solve that:

```
function strTimeToMinutes(str_time) {
  var arr_time = str_time.split(":");
  var hour = parseInt(arr_time[0]);
  var minutes = parseInt(arr_time[1]);
  return((hour * 60) + minutes);
}
```

And replace his definitions with:

```
var calMinTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("minTime"));
var calMaxTimeInMinutes = strTimeToMinutes(curCalView.opt("maxTime"));

var curSeconds = (( ((curTime.getHours() * 60) + curTime.getMinutes()) - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60) + curTime.getSeconds();                       
var percentOfDay = curSeconds / ((calMaxTimeInMinutes - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

Awesome solution, helped me a great deal, thank you everyone! These are the changes required to get this solution working with the new FullCalendar v2.

Change the line: `if (curCalView.visStart < curTime && curCalView.visEnd > curTime) {`

To: `if (curCalView.intervalStart < curTime && curCalView.intervalEnd > curTime) {`

And prefer to use: `viewRender: function(view) {`

instead of: `viewDisplay: function(view) {`

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this solution for version 2.3.2. It is based of previous examples.

```
    var timelineIntervalPromise;
    var renderCurrentTimeline = function(view, element, anchor) {
      var currentDate = moment().tz(security.currentUser.timeZone.id);
      var intervalStart = view.intervalStart.clone().tz(security.currentUser.timeZone.id)
        .year(view.intervalStart.year())
        .month(view.intervalStart.month())
        .day(view.intervalStart.day())
        .time('00:00:00');
      var intervalEnd = view.intervalEnd.clone().tz(security.currentUser.timeZone.id)
        .year(view.intervalEnd.year())
        .month(view.intervalEnd.month())
        .day(view.intervalEnd.day())
        .time('00:00:00');

      if (view.name === 'month' || !currentDate.isBetween(intervalStart, intervalEnd)) {
        return;
      }

      var timeGrid = element.find('.fc-time-grid');
      var timeline = angular.element('<hr class="timeline" />');
      timeGrid.find('hr.timeline').remove();
      timeGrid.prepend(timeline);

      var calMinTimeInMinutes = moment.duration(view.opt('minTime')).asMinutes();
      var calMaxTimeInMinutes = moment.duration(view.opt('maxTime')).asMinutes();
      var curSeconds = (( ((currentDate.hours() * 60) + currentDate.minutes()) - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60) + currentDate.seconds();
      var percentOfDay = curSeconds / ((calMaxTimeInMinutes - calMinTimeInMinutes) * 60);
      var topLoc = Math.floor(timeGrid.height() * percentOfDay);
      var timeCol = element.find('.fc-time:visible');
      timeline.css({top: topLoc, left: timeCol.outerWidth(true)});
      if (angular.isUndefined(anchor) || anchor === true) {
        timeGrid.parent().scrollTop(timeline.offset().top);
      }

      if (view.name === 'agendaWeek') { // Week view, don't want the timeline to go the whole way across.
        var dayCol = element.find('.fc-time-grid .fc-bg .fc-today');
        var left = dayCol.position().left + 1;
        var width = dayCol.width() + 1;
        timeline.css({left: left, width: width});
      }

      if (angular.isDefined(timelineIntervalPromise)) {
        $interval.cancel(timelineIntervalPromise);
      }
      timelineIntervalPromise = $interval(function() {
        var view = uiCalendarConfig.calendars.eventCalendar.fullCalendar('getView');
        renderCurrentTimeline(view, view.el, false);
      }, 300000);
    };
```

Comment: I want to use your solution, but I am new to angular, can you paste here some simple usage example. Thanks.

Comment: First of all I updated the timeline generation with current code.

Sorry Dragomir but there is no simple usage example. I would have to paste entire directive, which is proprietary software, so I cannot do that.

Simply said, you have to have all requirements injected into your controller that this function uses e.g. moment, $interval and others. Then in fullcalendar viewRender event, just call this function.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks a lot Vladimir.

Comment: For angular users, this is the best solution. @VladimírGorej I had to change `timeline.css({ top: topLoc, left: timeCol.outerWidth(true) });` to `timeline.css({ top: topLoc + 'px', left: timeCol.outerWidth(true) + 'px' });` for Chrome compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with version 2.2.7 when using custom min and max time I added

```
var slotsDiv  = $('.fc-slats:visible');
```

before the line

```
var parentDiv = $('.fc-slats:visible').parent();
```

and changed the line

```
var topLoc = Math.floor(parentDiv.height() * percentOfDay);
```

to

```
var topLoc = Math.floor(slotsDiv.height() * percentOfDay);
```

This way the function uses the correct div height to calculate the timeline position.